# How to wrap "AspectRatio" widget to avoid yellow/black overflow line?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, aspect-ratio, scrollable

This is my code(The complete project code : https://github.com/mitchkoko/responsivedesign):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class MyDesktopBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDesktopBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('D E S K T O P'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            // First column
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // videoplayer section
                  AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 16/9,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                    ),
                  ),
                    
                  // comment section
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 8,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                            height: 120,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
        
            // second column
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I extend the window size or decrease the window height I get the following error message:

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════ The following assertion was thrown
> during layout: A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.1 pixels on the bottom.
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was Column
> lib\responsive\desktop_body.dart:20 You can inspect this widget using
> the 'Inspect Widget' button in the VS Code notification. The
> overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical. The edge
> of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering
> with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the
> contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
>
> Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to
> force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space
> instead of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an
> error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot
> be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available
> space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it
> in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like
> a ListView.
>
> The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#cd135
> relayoutBoundary=up7 OVERFLOWING
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

I think the problem is the `AspectRatio` widget in videoplayer section. I don't know how to wrap this widget to prevent this error happening but when I comment out that part of the code, I will no longer get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the issue rise from `AspectRatio` on youtube player section when it tries to fill height based on width on small height with large width. You can wrap with `ConstrainedBox` to solve this issue.

```dart
body: LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        // First column
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // videoplayer section
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight - 16,
                ),
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
```

Full widget

```dart
class MyDesktopBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDesktopBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('D E S K T O P'),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              // First column
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    // videoplayer section
                    ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight - 16,
                      ),
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    // comment section
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 8,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                              height: 120,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              // second column
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 200,
                    color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally it worked and the problem resolved. But when I try to reduce the height of running window near to zero, at the end(when I reach to window height = 0) it gives me a new error. Do you know how can I also resolve this new error: `boxconstraints has non-normalized height constraints`?

Comment: This can be controlled from `constraints.maxHeight - 16,` you can check if the value gets smaller than zero or not. like `constraints.maxHeight - 16<0?0:constraints.maxHeight - 16,` or just dont render the widget like `if(constraints.maxHeight - 16>0)ConstrainedBox(`

Answer (score 0):

I dynamically changed the aspect ratio like this:

```
const desktopWidth = 1200;

////

child: AspectRatio(
   aspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < desktopWidth? 16 / 9 : 16 / 7,
child: Container(
.....
```